# Set the initial value to material ui select

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a TextField in Material UI used as Select. The MenuItems are working fine in the form, but I'm not being able to pre select an option based on data on a state previously populated

I have this , and as example I want to preselect "Familia 3" , What I'm supposed to set up?

```
<Textfield id="family" select value=0 defaultValue=3 >
   <MenuItem value="0">Seleccionar</MenuItem>
   <MenuItem value="1">Familia 1</MenuItem>
   <MenuItem value="2">Familia 2</MenuItem>
   <MenuItem value="3">Familia 3</MenuItem>
</TextField>
```

I tried changing Value, DefaultValue , removing one of them, and couldt find a solution
AI bet is very simple but I cant find any solution to show up with option "Familia 3" preselected

Can you help me with this?
Thanks !

Comment: I did read the question, it has no mention of docs or why you tried each of those things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default value is not applicable in the select TextField
set your initial value as the value prop.
You have misspelling in the Textfield opening tag it should be TextField
when assigning a non string value to an attribute always use curly brackets ie: value={3}

```
<TextField id="family" select value={3}>
    <MenuItem value="0">Seleccionar</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value="1">Familia 1</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value="2">Familia 2</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value="3">Familia 3</MenuItem>
</TextField>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store Familia 3 into the state and than set the value of text field to state

```
const [initial value, setinitialvalue ] = use state("Familia 
3")

<Textfield id="family" select value={initialValue} 
 onChange={(e) => setinitialvalue(e.target.value) } 
  defaultValue=3 >
    <MenuItem value="Seleccionar 
         ">Seleccionar</MenuItem>
   <MenuItem value="Familia 1">Familia 1</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value="Familia 2 ">Familia 2</MenuItem>
   <MenuItem value="Familia 3">Familia 3</MenuItem>
</TextField>
```